# Make an array with data linked to a select menu

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

(hopefully this problem hasn't been resolved yet) if so, I am sorry and please link me to the solution. (this is an exercise for the Java course I am attendind nowadays so I am quite novice with Javascript. )
I have a select menu with trip destinations. There are 4-5 destinations (Paris, London, Amsterdam, Berlin, New York..) For each destination there is a short description and a certain price. 
So the exercise says: when someone clicks on an option from the select menu , the appropriate description has to appear in the textarea and the appropriate price in the text input. (it's some basic stuff).. I know how some html objects work, I just can't seem to find the best way to do this with select object. I did it with checkboxes via name attribute and a for loop. with radiobuttons as well.. but with select options I am stuck. I don't need the solution for my exercise, I just need a sample code but something I understand. 
Ex: 

 Paris
etc

something like : for selected option [i], textarea.value = the description associated to each trip destination and text input.value = the price of the trip . 
I don't want something like : if selectedIndex[0]---textarea.value = X 
I need to do something like an Array of destinations.. trips[i] = new Array [] and fill the array of the trip array with the prices and the var's of the description strings.. (I hope I have been clear about everything I need . 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Define an object array where you make a key value mapping of each place and an index.

```
 var array = [{'key': 0, 'value': 'Paris'},{'key': 1, 'value': 'London'},{'key': 2: 'value': 'Amsterdam'}...]
```

Loop through the array and populate your select options:

```
 <select>
 {array.map((each)=>{return (<option value= each.key></option>)})}
 </select>
```

In your event handler, map the key to value in the array to get your text.

```
 selectHandler(val){
    let result = array.find((each)=>{return each.key === val});
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textArea');
    textarea.value = result.value;
 }
```

Comment: ?? thanks for the answer.. I understand a bit of the code but some of the methods there just make me freak out :) map? array.find(each) say whaat??:) .. is that javascript ? if it is so , it means I am veryyy basic leveled .. Sorry, i need something more .. easy to understand/do .. Your code makes sense .. a bit  but not everything... sorry.

Comment: hey, map and find are really simple Javascript functions. Basically, array.map takes a function as input and runs it on each element of the array. It then returns an output array where each element is f(x) where x is the corresponding input array element. array.find simply takes a function as input and returns the first element where the function evaluates to true. In this case it would return the element where value of the array = the selected option.

Comment: You can study more about javascript functions here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: wow, I am at a very  basic level then,:) I admit . i'm like at level 1 out of 100 :)) I will try your solution tomorrow (it's night my time now) and come back with an answer . Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.. textArea.value = description[selectOption.value];